# Performance of SQL Query.

Tags: sql

How can i speed up the below sql query, because its taking 13 secs for only 23 records.
Already used temp table instead of table variable but not so good. 
Can i use some other Joins or splits the condition into two parts or Is it the Indexing issue?

```
   INSERT INTO #Fulfill (
    [ordergroup_id]
    ,[lineitem_id]
    ,[CreateDate]
    ,[CreateTime]
    ,[UserID]
    ,[CreatedBy]
    ,[Model]
    ,[Year]
    ,[SKU]
    ,[Manufacturer]
    ,[ProductName]
    ,[OrderReference]
    ,[Status]
    ,[NetworkPO]
    ,[TrackingNo]
    ,[ShippingNote]
    ,[CarrierName]
    ,[TrackingURL]
    ,[PartCost]
    ,[EstShipping]
    ,[DMSPONo]
    ,[PODate]
    ,[Vendor]
    ,[d_DateCreated]
    ,[StatusCode]
    ,[LocationOrderCutoff]
    ,[ReleasedDate]
    ,[Source]
    ,[Make]
    ,[Submodel]
    ,[RejectedReason]
    ,[ProductID]
    ,[OrderedFor]
    ,[Customer Business Card]
    ,[LeadStoreID]
    ,[ScheduledInstallDate]
    ,[InstallCompleteDate]
    ,[RONumber]
    ,[VIN]
    ,[LeadSource]
    ,[StoreADICount]
    )
SELECT OFLI.ordergroup_id
    ,OFLI.lineitem_id
    ,convert(VARCHAR(10), OFLI.d_DateCreated, 101) [CreateDate]
    ,SUBSTRING(convert(VARCHAR(20), OFLI.d_DateCreated, 100), 13, 7) [CreateTime]
    ,CASE ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), OFH.SalespersonID), '')
        WHEN ''
            THEN OFH.user_id
        ELSE OFH.SalespersonID
        END [UserID]
    ,ISNULL(UO.firstname, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(UO.lastname, '') [CreatedBy]
    ,OFH.Model [Model]
    ,OFH.VehicleYear [Year]
    ,ACI.SKU
    ,AB.BrandDescription [Manufacturer]
    ,ACI.Caption [ProductName]
    ,OFH.OrderReference
    ,ISNULL(CASE isnull(OFLI.PurchaseOrderRef, '')
            WHEN ''
                THEN 'Pending'
            ELSE isNull(AGSM.CustomStatusDesc, S.StatusDescription)
            END, '&nbsp;') [Status]
    ,SUBSTRING(OFLI.PurchaseOrderRef, 0, PATINDEX('%.%', OFLI.PurchaseOrderRef)) [NetworkPO]
    ,POLI.TrackingNo
    ,POLI.ShippingNote
    ,C.CarrierName
    ,C.TrackingURL
    ,POLI.UnitCost AS [PartCost]
    ,POLI.EstShipping AS [EstShipping]
    ,PO.DMSPONo
    ,convert(VARCHAR(10), PO.ReleaseDate, 101) [PODate]
    ,CASE 
        WHEN SP.SupplierID IS NULL
            THEN SRC.SourceName
        ELSE SP.SupplierName
        END [Vendor]
    ,OFLI.d_DateCreated
    ,CASE isnull(OFLI.PurchaseOrderRef, '')
        WHEN ''
            THEN 0
        ELSE ISNULL(POLI.StatusCode, 1)
        END [StatusCode]
    ,isNull(SPL.LocationOrderCutoff, '00:00') [LocationOrderCutoff]
    ,PO.ReleaseDate AS ReleasedDate
    ,0 [Source]
    ,OFH.Make AS [Make]
    ,OFH.Trim AS [Submodel]
    ,ISNULL(POLI.RejectedReason, '') [RejectedReason]
    ,OFLI.product_id [ProductID]
    ,OFH.OrderedFor AS OrderedFor
    ,NULL AS [Customer Business Card]
    ,OFH.user_org_name AS [LeadStoreID]
    ,OFLI.ScheduledInstallDate
    ,OFLI.InstallCompleteDate
    ,OFLI.RONumber
    ,OFH.VIN
    ,OFH.LeadSource
    ,dbo.ASM_GetADIInventoryCount(OFLI.product_id, '', '', @StoreID, 0)
FROM OrderFormLineItems OFLI(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN OrderFormHeader OFH(NOLOCK) ON OFLI.ordergroup_id = OFH.ordergroup_id
INNER JOIN OrderGroup OG(NOLOCK) ON OFLI.ordergroup_id = OG.ordergroup_id
    AND OG.order_status_code IN (
        4
        ,8
        )
INNER JOIN CATALOG.dbo.ASMCatalogItems ACI(NOLOCK) ON ACI.ItemID = OFLI.product_id
INNER JOIN CATALOG.dbo.ASMBrands AB(NOLOCK) ON AB.BrandCode = ACI.BrandCode
INNER JOIN UserObject UO(NOLOCK) ON UO.g_id = (
        CASE ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), OFH.SalespersonID), '')
            WHEN ''
                THEN OFH.user_id
            ELSE OFH.SalespersonID
            END
        )
LEFT JOIN ASMPurchaseOrder PO(NOLOCK) ON PO.PONumber = SUBSTRING(OFLI.PurchaseOrderRef, 0, PATINDEX('%.%', OFLI.PurchaseOrderRef))
LEFT JOIN ASMPurchaseOrderLineItemDetails POLI(NOLOCK) ON PO.PONumber = POLI.PONumber
    AND OFLI.PurchaseOrderRef = CONVERT(VARCHAR, POLI.PONumber) + '.' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, POLI.POLineItemNo)
LEFT JOIN ASMStatus S(NOLOCK) ON S.StatusType = 'POLI'
    AND S.StatusCode = POLI.StatusCode
LEFT JOIN ASMGroupStatusMapping AGSM(NOLOCK) ON S.StatusCode = AGSM.StatusCode
    AND AGSM.StatusTypeID = 2
    AND AGSM.GroupID = @GroupID
LEFT JOIN ASMCarriers C(NOLOCK) ON C.CarrierID = POLI.CarrierID
LEFT JOIN ASMSupplierLocations SPL(NOLOCK) ON SPL.SupplierLocationID = PO.SupplierLocationID
LEFT JOIN ASMSuppliers SP(NOLOCK) ON SP.SupplierID = SPL.SupplierID
LEFT JOIN ASMSource SRC(NOLOCK) ON PO.SourceID = SRC.SourceID
LEFT JOIN UserObject UO2(NOLOCK) ON OFH.OrderedFor = UO2.g_id
WHERE OFLI.line_Item_Status_Code <> 4
    AND OFH.OrderReference > ''
    AND (
        @DMSPONo = ''
        OR @DMSPONo = PO.DMSPONo
        )
    AND (
        POLI.PONumber = @NetworkPO
        OR @NetworkPO IS NULL
        )
    AND (
        @VendorName = ''
        OR SP.SupplierName LIKE '%' + @VendorName + '%'
        )
    AND (
        @CreatedByID IS NULL
        OR OFH.user_id = @CreatedByID
        )
    AND (
        @OrderReference = ''
        OR OFH.OrderReference LIKE '%' + @OrderReference + '%'
        OR UO2.FirstName LIKE '%' + @OrderReference + '%'
        OR UO2.LastName LIKE '%' + @OrderReference + '%'
        OR UO2.Organization LIKE '%' + @OrderReference + '%'
        )
    AND (
        @Keyword = ''
        OR ACI.SKU LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%'
        OR AB.BrandDescription LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%'
        OR ACI.Caption LIKE '%' + @Keyword + '%'
        )
    AND (
        @ORDER_DATE_1 IS NULL
        OR @ORDER_DATE_1 = '1/1/1900'
        OR (
            OFLI.d_DateCreated BETWEEN @ORDER_DATE_1
                AND CASE 
                        WHEN @ORDER_DATE_2 IS NULL
                            THEN GETDATE()
                        ELSE @ORDER_DATE_2
                        END
            )
        )
    AND (
        @PO_Date_1 IS NULL
        OR @PO_Date_1 = '1/1/1900'
        OR (
            PO.ReleaseDate BETWEEN @PO_Date_1
                AND CASE 
                        WHEN @PO_Date_2 IS NULL
                            THEN GETDATE()
                        ELSE @PO_Date_2
                        END
            )
        )
    AND (
        @Source = 0
        OR (
            @Source = 1
            AND EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM UserObject UO2(NOLOCK)
                WHERE UO2.G_id = OFH.user_ID
                    AND UO2.UserRole <> 1
                )
            )
        OR (
            @Source = 2
            AND EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM UserObject UO2(NOLOCK)
                WHERE UO2.G_id = OFH.user_ID
                    AND UO2.UserRole = 1
                )
            )
        )
    AND (
        (
            @WithCustomer = 1
            AND @WithoutCustomer = 1
            )
        OR (
            @WithCustomer = 1
            AND @WithoutCustomer = 0
            AND OFH.OrderedFor IS NOT NULL
            )
        OR (
            @WithCustomer = 0
            AND @WithoutCustomer = 1
            AND OFH.OrderedFor IS NULL
            )
        )
    AND OFH.user_org_name = @StoreID --@STOREID_TMP 
    AND OFLI.product_id NOT LIKE '%$%'
    AND OFLI.product_id NOT LIKE '[#]%'
    AND OFLI.product_id NOT LIKE '%(%'
    AND OFLI.product_id NOT LIKE '%*%'
    AND ACI.SKU NOT LIKE 'DTPACKAGE%'
```

Comment: You got to be kidding...

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan for the query?

Comment: Index on `UserObject.UserRole`, those `like %+` maybe better `INSTR()`. Small stuff: `COALESCE`. Using views for the `EXISTS` (G_id and booleans `UserRole<>1, =1`). **A rare case for not retrieving all data from the database at once.**

Comment: Code like this `CASE 
                        WHEN @ORDER_DATE_2 IS NULL
                            THEN GETDATE()
                        ELSE @ORDER_DATE_2
                        END` you can change to `ISNULL(@ORDER_DATE_2, GETDATE())` OR `COALESCE(@ORDER_DATE_2, GETDATE())`

Comment: It's really strange that it is so slow, especially since you have been pushing the magic `(NOLOCK)` button 17 times.

Comment: The problem is your `WHERE` clause there cheif. It's ridiculous. It has got to go. Find another way to get the information you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, SQL queries sometimes take time to execute.

Reasons:

- If the tables used in the lists are not combined using `foreign` and `primary keys`.
- If the query has multiple tables and joins are using string values in comparisons. *(For this purpose it is a good practice to make joins using numeric values.)*
- If the tables involved do not have indexes. *(Indexes make an SQL query run fast.)*
- There are other reasons which make an SQL query run slow.

I will suggest you check these things for your tables description.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "optional" parameters, you should built up the query dynamically using only the active filters.
It might get you a tremedous speedup.

If you can't built up the query on the fly, maybe you could then make a set of Stored Procedure specific to some parameters combination.

If you can't do that either then at least use the query hint WITH RECOMPILE.